# Return observable from .net web api

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, rxjs-observables

Specifically my question is about how to return a true observable from a .netcore web api controller, using efcore. This is so datasets can be returned as a stream so the front end can start building the page at once using the data that it receives in the first iteration and keep on until all data has been received.

So I have seen observable collections. I have also seen that EFCore now streams rather than buffers.

Can anyone point me at the documentation, or an example so I can do more reading?

Let's say I am returning 20 records, from my web api and returning them to a reactjs project. Reactjs supports observables using rxjs. What do I need to do in the web api app to support this observable flow from sql server all the way up to the controller level?

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what are you asking for , but the normal process is create a service which return a DTO, in your case an array of DTOs or a DTO which contains an array of DTOs.
And then you can send this info trough the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if WebAPI is able to stream `IObservable` out-of-the-box (most probably not), so there are 2 options:

1. you can use SinglarR sockets to stream objects to frontend
2. You can return `IAsyncEnumerable` from controller. This way JSON serializer will stream the data element by element and frontend needs to start deserializing them before getting whole result

Personally, I'd use approach 2, unless you already use websockets in your project. In the controller it's mostly a matter of using `ToAsyncEnumerable` (here's a [source](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/main/Ix.NET/Source/System.Linq.Async/System/Linq/Operators/ToAsyncEnumerable.Observable.cs)), but you need to verify, if your frontend libraries support that